# Azure DevOps pipeline is cancelled when another project is queued

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-server-2020

This seams to be opposite to problem the majority of people are having.

Basically, we have the default pool with a number of agents listed. A pipeline build is requested and allocated to an agent, an agent is allocated no problem. Once all the agents are processing a pipeline the next pipeline that is requested, won't join a queue. One of the currently active pipelines will be cancelled and the new pipeline is started.

This is not what I would expect, previous build engines queued the new request until an agent became available.

Is there some configuration for this somewhere I have look in the usually places.

- Project Settings / Agent Pools
- Collection Settings / Agent Pools

Azure DevOps Server 2020

Classic Pipelines

Each requested pipeline is from a different team project and different set of code.

Comment: Post your pipeline YAML.

Comment: @DanielMann I am using classic.

Comment: Please create a new pipeline with simple definition for a check, will it have same appearance? If not, compare the settings between two pipelines.

Comment: @wadezhou-MSFT two new pipelines, and a new queue, same issue.